# Get JSON list of apps from Heroku account

Tags: node.js, json, express, heroku

Making a Node/Express app to be my portfolio.

Using this CLI command, I'm able to see a JSON list of my apps and their properties within the CLI itself: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#app-commands

How can I use this CLI command to be able to use this data within backend node/express code?

My goal is to have Node collect data for all of my apps from Heroku and loop through them to display the title/description on a page with a link to the app.

I've installed the NPM package for Heroku, and so far all I've figured out how to do is get it to start a Heroku shell within my terminal when the Node instance is run, not how to actually return the information from Heroku into the app itself to be used to display on the page.

Comment: You'd want to use [the API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference), not the CLI.

Comment: According to the [Apps API Reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#app-list) I would basically use `const apps = await curl -n https://api.heroku.com/apps \`?

Comment: Once you've got an access token, essentially yes.

Comment: @ceejayoz I guess I'm not as smart as I thought, 'cause I'm having serious trouble. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @ceejayoz Nevermind, I got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty! Figured out how to get it working with Axios!

Also had to use the Heroku CLI to generate an OAUTH token:

```
heroku authorizations:create
```

And then throw that into an Environment Variable `process.env.HEROKU_TOKEN`

```
async getLandingPage(req,res,next) {
        try {
            const projects = await axios.get('https://api.heroku.com/apps',{headers: 
                {
                Accept: "application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.HEROKU_TOKEN}`
                }
            });
            console.log(projects);
            res.render('index', {projects, page:'home'});
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

Man, I feel really dumb that it took that long to figure it out. Hopefully I'll be smarter about it in the future.